# How to recover the deleted file from linux system?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, linux-kernel

I am using centos7 locally. Mistaken I deleted text file(keystone.conf.disabled) using rm, from /etc/httpd/conf.d directory, How to recover this file. This file is very important to me. Please help me..

I try to but in vain It is giving message Filesystem n

```
[vagrant@localhost conf.d]$ debugfs -w /dev/mapper/wks01-root
debugfs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/mapper/wks01-root: No such file or directory while opening filesystem
debugfs:  lsdel
lsdel: Filesystem not open
debugfs:
```

I try also using as root user

```
[vagrant@localhost conf.d]$ su
Password: 
[root@localhost conf.d]# debugfs -w /dev/mapper/wks01-root
debugfs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/mapper/wks01-root: No such file or directory while opening filesystem
debugfs:  lsdel
lsdel: Filesystem not open
debugfs:
```

Comment: You should have backups.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for suggestion, but how can we take back-up of config file, If you answer please help..

Comment: You should backup `/etc/` (and also your `/home/`) periodically, e.g. thru some `crontab` job.

Comment: `etckeeper` should help here. It's generally a good idea to keep config files in version control. You could always get a remote and push to it if you fear your harddrive might crash.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the system is remounted **read-only** to prevent the released diskspace from being overwritten and try `extundelete` if you're on **ext3/4**.

For the future, `etckeeper` might be useful (makes a git repo out of `etc` and commits on installs that change `/etc/`)